# Battery Power Icon won't display on top bar

Tags: icons, battery, menu-bar

I have a surface book 2, and recently updated my OS from windows to ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS.

I'm running into a problem when trying to update the top bar of the UI to show the battery percentage status.

I've ran this command to enable the battery icon, but no luck

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface show-battery-percentage true
```

I've also downloaded the "Tweaks" application, and toggled the battery percentage switch to ON. However, nothing.

I've rebooted my system, but nothing as well.

Checking the power stats shows that the battery is not been recognized.
[image: Power Statitistics]

Thank you in advance for debugging this.

Best,
Alvaro

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to AskUbuntu, Alvaro.

To get this working on your SurfaceBook 2, you'll need to install some ACPI drivers so that the battery (and other devices) can be accessed. Here's how to do it:

1. Open a terminal (`[Ctrl]`+`[Alt]`+`[T]`)
2. Install the necessary tools to work with the source code you're going to need:
   `sudo apt install build-essential dkms git`
3. Move to a "safe" working directory, for example:
   `cd ~/Downloads`
4. Clone the ACPI drivers from GitHub to your machine:
   `git clone https://github.com/qzed/linux-surfacegen5-acpi`
5. Go to the `module` directory:
   `cd linux-surfacegen5-acpi/module/`
6. Compile the module:
   `make`
7. Install the module:
   `sudo insmod surfacegen5_acpi.ko`
   `sudo make dkms-install`

The battery indicator should appear 5~10 seconds after installing the module.